# Can I change the URL of a YouTube video?

Tags: youtube, youtube-live

I am currently doing some live-streaming on YouTube. When the stream is live, I want it to be public. After the stream is over, I'd like the recording to be unlisted, but with a different URL. The obvious way to do this, to my mind, is to change the URL and make it unlisted, but I can't see how to do the first part.

Is this possible? I know it can be done on Facebook, but I can't see how to do it on YouTube. I don't really want to upload the whole thing a second time if I can avoid it.